# Disable <mat-checkbox> after a certain count

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular-material

So I am trying to print a list and each list element has a checkbox inside it. Let's say I have a list of 10 elements, I want to be able to check only 5, and the remaining ones should be disabled. Once the user unchecks any element, he/she should be able to select again.

Sample Code:

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list"
                 (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" *ngIf="templatearray.length !== 0">
              <div class="example-box"
                   *ngFor="let key2 of templatearray" cdkDrag>{{key2}}
                <div>
                  <button mat-icon-button type="button" class="buttonCustom">
                    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" (change)="onChange($event)"></mat-checkbox>
                  </button>
                  <button mat-icon-button type="button" class="buttonCustom">
                  <span class="material-icons">
                   remove_circle
                   </span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Sample stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9grcqt?file=src/app/app.component.ts

If I add [disabled] attribute, all the checkboxes are disabled
[image: This is how it looks when I add disabled attribute]

Answer (score 1):

On `*ngFor`, you can get the index for each item like

```
*ngFor="let key2 of templatearray; let i = index"
```

And based on that `i` (index variable), you can disable the `mat-checkbox` from the specific point.

For example, if you want to disable checkboxes from the 5th, you can set as follows.

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" (change)="onChange($event)" [disabled]="i > 4"></mat-checkbox>
```

This is the completed codes.

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" *ngIf="templatearray.length !== 0">
  <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let key2 of templatearray; let i = index" cdkDrag>{{key2}}
    <div>
      <button mat-icon-button type="button" class="buttonCustom">
        <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" color="warn" (change)="onChange($event)" [disabled]="i > 5"></mat-checkbox>
      </button>
      <button mat-icon-button type="button" class="buttonCustom">
        <span class="material-icons">
          remove_circle
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not sure if I wrote the question in an ambiguous way, but the approach that you have mentioned enables the first 6 checkboxes.
Take a scenario where the list contains 10 elements and I want to enable the user to select only 5.

However, by this approach, the last 5 are disabled by default and users cannot select them at all.

FYI: I have updated my question with a screenshot.

Comment: You can do that by changing the value of `[disabled]="i > 5"`, if you want to enable first 3 items only, use `[disabled]="i > 2"`, and now, want to enable first 5 items, `[disabled]="i > 4"`.

Comment: The remaining ones should be disabled after the user selects/clicks a checkbox

Comment: In that case, you can set new variable which represents if the button is clicked or not, for example, `isDisableSelected` and use like this. `[disabled]="i > 5 && isDisableSelected"`